# Recognize swipe gesture in UIScrollView only when scrolling content reach the edge

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have `UIScrollView` with vertical scroll active. What I am trying to do is to add a swipe gesture with direction `.down` which will be recognized when the user cannot scroll the content anymore because it reaches the edge.

I was trying with require(toFail:) but it doesn't work properly.

```
let swipeDown = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.respondToSwipeGesture))
swipeDown.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.down
swipeDown.require(toFail: self.scrollView.panGestureRecognizer)
self.scrollView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDown)
```

I have also added `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` method to recognize simultaneously:

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
}
```

How to give always priority to scrolling content inside scrollView and when it is not possible anymore to detect swipe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, the way I have managed that issue was simply check if the contentOffset reaches point 0.0, and if yes then disable scrolling and activate additional gesture. For my case that was enough.

```
if scrollView.contentOffset.y == 0.0 {
    print("content on top")

    // use delegate method here to manage the gestures

}
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue and I would like to learn from your post. As I am a quite beginner of iOS development, would it be possible for you to post a larger version of the code including `if scrollView.content...` looks like? I would like to know where you put the part in a larger picture and how does the delegate method looks like. Please and thank you!